# Не удаляется файл cookie или как переопределить / удалить cookie в curl-запросе

Tags: php, curl, cookie

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'patch_to_file');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'patch_to_file');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'data');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'url');
        curl_exec($ch);

        var_export(unlink('patch_to_file')); //true, но файл все равно присутствует по указанному пути
```

Почему не удаляется файл в который записаны куки?

Мне нужно снести куку для дальнейшей работы, не закрывая сессию curl

Comment: есть одно наблюдение: если закрыть сеанс curl - curl_close($ch) то файл удаляется как надо, но мне нужно дальше по коду продолжить работать именно с этим идентификатором курла

Comment: тогда удаляйте в самом конце, без curl_close файл залочен процессом курла, вы не можете его удалить, ну, точнее, может быть и можете, в зависимости от ос, но не должны так делать.

Comment: так мне нужно снести куку для дальнейшей работы

Comment: ну а curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: test=cookie")); чем не устраивает? ставишь ее в свое значение. И в целом, у тебя вопрос один (почему файл не удаляется), а на самом деле совсем другой (как снести куку в курле)

Comment: т.е. ты просто не передаешь нужную куку или передаешь пустое значение (если тебе нужно) в php manual: Note that multiple cookies are separated with a semicolon followed by a space (e.g., "fruit=apple; colour=red"

Answer (score 1):

1) файл не удаляется потому, что используется курлом, потому, что ты не вызвал (как сам нашел) `curl_close`. По крайней мере в линуксе, unlink вернет тебе true, типа "удаление ок", но пока файл используется живыми процессами, удален он не будет. А вот после выхода из скрипта - скорее всего исчезнет окончательно. Если ты его каким-нибудь другим процессом не подхватишь до выхода скрипта.

2) если тебе нужно переопределить или удалить куки, используй

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: test=cookie"));`
или CURLOPT_COOKIE
можешь сделать заголовок пустым (не посылать куки), передать нужные куки (через `;`) переопределить нужные и т.д.